# webkit-gradient not appending in FF

Tags: css, webkit

Basically, the following code doesn't seem to append to my table TH inside FireFox

```
.table th {
   font-weight: bold;
   background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.03, #3A79C1), color-stop(0.99, #5F9EE6), color-stop(1, #75ABEA) );
   color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #666;
}
```

The text shadow is appending just not the background

Answer (score 0):

You are only using the -webkit-gradient directive, but to make FF see your gradient you should add also the -moz-linear-gradient directive!

Comment: And examples on how please ?

Comment: @CurtisCrewe - and rewrite the colour stops - the ColorZilla gradient editor (http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) is very useful for generating cross-browser CSS3 gradients

Comment: I don't even understand that, can someone just re-write it for me please so i can understand it through that ?

Comment: Sorry, I was on the fly, I guess Perfect Dark answer will explain it better than mine... :)